# Voting Election

Tags: custom-fields, joomla

I am reviewing the Civic CRM Election component for Joomla.  I have created some basic election information and nominees.  I need to add Amendments for this election.  I don't where I would add this.  Would I have to create custom fields?  I haven't found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are interested in this feature request, https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.elections/issues/5

In terms of custom fields, you can add them to Contacts in the Election. But then would need to update the templates to show the values.

The other Election entities, such as Election, Vote and others used specifically for the Election do not support custom fields.

The standard CiviCRM entities, of course do. So would recommend trying to use those.